# why do I get different hash value everytime I call hexdigest() in hashlib?

Tags: python, hash

I want to have a unique hash for the same string in python. I use following code for getting a hash :

```
import hashlib
mysha1 = hashlib.sha1()
mysha1.update("my_url")
print mysha1.hexdigest()
mysha1.update("my_url")
print mysha1.hexdigest() # which is generating a different hash
```

is there something I missed here?

Comment: The second time, you're getting the hash of the string `"my_urlmy_url"`.  Now read the answers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do not call `update` more than once, for example:

```py
>>> import hashlib
>>> mysha1 = hashlib.sha1()
>>> mysha1.update("my_url")
>>> mysha1.hexdigest()
'ebde90b9f0c047ff9f86bec3b71afe5d00594030'
>>> mysha1.hexdigest()
'ebde90b9f0c047ff9f86bec3b71afe5d00594030'
```

Answer (score 7):

the `update()` function feeds strings to be concatenated.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> mysha1 = hashlib.sha1()
>>> mysha1.update("my_url")
>>> print mysha1.hexdigest()
ebde90b9f0c047ff9f86bec3b71afe5d00594030
>>> mysha1.update("my_url")
>>> print mysha1.hexdigest()
efa6ba48cedd0da886a553ad0e7c131ec79b452e
>>> 
>>> 
>>> sha = hashlib.sha1()
>>> sha.update("my_urlmy_url")
>>> print sha.hexdigest()
efa6ba48cedd0da886a553ad0e7c131ec79b452e
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call `update("my_url")`, you're [concatenating](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) that string to the hash input.

> You can now feed this object with arbitrary strings using the update() method. At any point you can ask it for the digest of the concatenation of the strings fed to it so far using the digest() or hexdigest() methods.

You need to make a new `sha1` object every time you want a new hash.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way:

```
import hashlib    
print(hashlib.sha1(str("my_url").encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```